# Addition of a row as per condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a temporary table in which I want to add one row below each employee. Here `@STARTDATE` is 1st August 2015 which is changable.

It should check the conditions like:

```
WHEN (JoiningDate of employee) > @STARTDATE THEN
   Case 
    When (EXPECTEDSTARTDATE(Its a project start date) = (JoiningDate of employee) Then NULL
    When (EXPECTEDSTARTDATE > (JoiningDate of employee) Then (Daysallocated)*8)-SUM(InstallCapacity))

  End
WHEN (JoiningDate of employee) = @STARTDATE THEN
  Case 
    When (EXPECTEDSTARTDATE = @STARTDATE) Then NULL
    When (EXPECTEDSTARTDATE > @STARTDATE) Then (Daysallocated)*8)-SUM(InstallCapacity))

  End
```

My table is

[image]

I am getting result as

[image]

I have added row as below

```
INSERT INTO #tempelevan 
SELECT EMPLOYEECODE, EMPLOYEENAME, 'Jayaraj Mariadhas Nadar' AS ReportingTo , 'Bench' AS PROJECTNAME, [Resource Pool] AS [Resource Pool], NULL AS ResourceStatus, ORGROLE AS ORGROLE,
[Resource DU] AS [Resource DU], [Resource DT] AS [Resource DT], NULL AS EXPECTEDSTARTDATE, NULL AS EXPECTEDENDDATE, NULL AS ResourcePercentage, NULL AS DaysAllocated, 
CASE 
 WHEN ((SELECT emp.joiningdate FROM tbl_pm_employee emp WHERE emp.employeecode=ft.EMPLOYEECODE) > @STARTDATE)
 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN (ft.EXPECTEDSTARTDATE = (SELECT emp.JoiningDate FROM tbl_pm_employee emp WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.EMPLOYEECODE)) 
        THEN NULL 
        WHEN (ft.EXPECTEDSTARTDATE > (SELECT emp.JoiningDate FROM tbl_pm_employee emp WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.EMPLOYEECODE)) 
        THEN ((SELECT dbo.countemployeebusinessdays(ft. employeecode, (SELECT emp.joiningdate FROM tbl_pm_employee emp WHERE emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode), @ENDDATE)*8)-sum(installcapacity)) 
    END
 WHEN ((SELECT emp.joiningdate FROM tbl_pm_employee emp WHERE emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode) = @STARTDATE)
 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN (ft.expectedstartdate = @STARTDATE) 
        THEN NULL 
        WHEN (ft.expectedstartdate > @STARTDATE) 
        THEN ((SELECT dbo.countemployeebusinessdays(ft. employeecode, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE))*8)-sum(installcapacity)
    END
END installcapacity, 
(1 - SUM([ActualAllocationPercentage])) as ActualPercentage
FROM #tempelevan ft GROUP BY ft.EMPLOYEECODE, ft.EMPLOYEENAME, ft.[Resource Pool], ft.ORGROLE, ft.[Resource DU], ft.[Resource DT], ft.EXPECTEDSTARTDATE
```

Here in result table there should be only a single row of Bench for particular employee but I am getting issue of multiple rows. It is showing row if there are multiple projects assigned to same employee.

Further I want to hide the rows whose Install capacity is Null.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the images, replacing them with formatted text.

Comment: Please help us help you by removing the images and replace them with consumable data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can't replace the images but I have changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. Can't keep in comments so, added here.

```
INSERT INTO #tempelevan SELECT EMPLOYEECODE, EMPLOYEENAME, 17ayaraj Mariadhas Hadar' AS reportinglo , 'Bench' AS projectname, [Resource Pool] AS [Resource Pool], NULL AS resourcestatus, orgrole AS orgrole, [Resource DU] AS [Resource DU], [Resource DT] AS [Resource DT], NULL AS expectedstartdate, NULL AS expectedenddate, NULL AS resourcepercentage, NULL AS daysallocated,CASE
WHEN 
  ( 
         SELECT emp.joiningdate 
         FROM   tbl_pm_employee emp 
         WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode) > @STARTDATE THEN 
  CASE 
  WHEN ( 
      ft.expectedstartdate = 
      ( 
             SELECT emp.joiningdate 
             FROM   tbl_pm_employee emp 
             WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode) 
    ) 
    THEN 
    NULL 
  WHEN ( 
      ft.expectedstartdate > 
      ( 
             SELECT emp.joiningdate 
             FROM   tbl_pm_employee emp 
             WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode) 
    ) 
    THEN 
    ( 
    ( 
           SELECT dbo.countemployeebusinessdays(ft. employeecode, 
                  ( 
                         SELECT emp. joiningdate 
                         FROM   tbl_pm_employee emp 
                         WHERE  emp.employeecode=ft.employeecode), @ENDDATE)*8)-sum(installcapacity)) 
  END --WHEN (select emp.JoiningDate from TBL_PM_EMPLOYEE emp where emp.EmployeeCode=ft.EMPLOYEECODE) < @STARTDATE   WHEN (select emp.JoiningDate from TBL_PM_EMPLOYEE emp where emp.EmployeeCode=ft.EMPLOYEECODE) = @STARTDATE THEN Case When (ft.EXPECTEDSTARTDATE = @STARTDATE) Then NULL When (ft.EXPECTEDSTARTDATE > @STARTDATE) Then ((select dbo.CountEmployeeBusinessDays(ft.EMPLOYEECODE, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE)*6)-SUM(InstallCapacity)) 
END 
END 
installcapacity, (1 - sumuactualallocationpercentagell) AS actualpercentage FROM #tempelevan ft GROUP BY ft.employeecode, ft.employeename, ft.[Resource Pool], ft.orgrole, ft.[Resource DU], ft.[Resource DT], ft.expectedstartdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. M getting error msg like "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: The code I updated in your question may not be right. Can you replace the SQL Query code in the question?

Comment: I have changed the code as per your suggestion it needs to check one more condition which is mandatory. I tried it but it doesn't work. In else condition somewhere something is going wrong.

Comment: Muks, if this is not an answer, would you explain in the body of the post what it is? Is it a partial answer? Posts that are not answer tend to get removed here.

Comment: I'll delete this, Initially the developer asked  a question which was an image formatted SQL Script. Instead of text format.